# Using Pelican Static Site Generator for something other than a blog

Tags: python, markdown, pelican, static-site, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to use the Pelican Static Site Generator to create a static site which is not a blog.

Each markdown file inside the `content/posts` folder contains the following data.

```
---
name: Product Name here
price: Product Price goes here
image: Product Image goes here 
---

The description content in Markdown goes here
```

But when I preview the site, I'm getting this error message: **Skipping filename.md: could not find information about 'title'**. I get the same error message if I move all the markdown files into the `content/pages` folder.

I would like to display the product information (which is stored in markdown files as shown above) on the homepage (index.html)

How do I get the content inside the posts folder not to be treated as articles or in other words make the title & date metadata optional for articles?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't give your pages titles? Why not use the title to hold the product name? And if you don't want your pages to be dated articles, then they *need* to go in `content/pages`.

Comment: You could use the title as the product name in this example, but lets assume it wasn't called title and also that for some other data it might not make sense to have a title field.

Comment: So you want to use a tool for something other than its intended purpose and you're not willing to make some compromises. Then I'm afraid I can't help, except to suggest that you find a different tool.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `name` field to `title`:

```
---
title: Product Name here
price: Product Price goes here
image: Product Image goes here 
---

The description content in Markdown goes here
```

There is little semantic difference between the two, but Pelican needs the `title` feed to be there. Alternatively, just set it to a unused value:

```
---
title: none
name: Product Name here
price: Product Price goes here
image: Product Image goes here 
---

The description content in Markdown goes here
```